# How to add multiple columns at once by dict in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"body": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]})
>>> df
  body
0  abc
1  def
2  ghi
```

and I have a magic function just for demo

```
def magic(string):
    return {"first": string[0], "second": string[1]}
```

is there a way I could quickly apply this function to the df and add all values in the return dict back to the df(i.e., so the df will have a head of ["body", "first", "second"]?

Updated:

Output example:

```
>>> df_out
  body first second
0  abc     a      b
1  def     d      e
2  ghi     g      h
```

Updated 1:
The real "magic" function is pretty large: it will take one field in the df and return a dict with len ~= 100. So efficiency matters a lot.

Comment: can you share an example of the expected output?

Comment: If you care of performance and efficiency, then think of providing a __reproducible__ function sample, so that we could try to find a __vectorized__ solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can proceed as follows for example:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({"body": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]})

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
  body
0  abc
1  def
2  ghi

In [7]: df.body.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"first": x[0], "second": x[1]}))
Out[7]: 
  first second
0     a      b
1     d      e
2     g      h

In [8]: df[['first','second']] = df.body.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"first": x[0], "second": x[1]}))

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
  body first second
0  abc     a      b
1  def     d      e
2  ghi     g      h
```

---

**using your magic function:**

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({"body": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]})

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
  body
0  abc
1  def
2  ghi

In [13]: def magic(string):
   ....:         return {"first": string[0], "second": string[1]}
   ....: 

In [14]: df[['first','second']] = df.body.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(magic(x)))
In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
  body first second
0  abc     a      b
1  def     d      e
2  ghi     g      h
```

---

**EDIT:** 
As per your question in the comments below, you can use df.join to not have to write the names of the columns explicitly:

```
In [39]: df.join(df.body.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(magic(x))))
Out[39]: 
  body first second
0  abc     a      b
1  def     d      e
2  ghi     g      h
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way that I could: 1) use my function 2) do not write the columns explicitly like in line In[14], i.e., ["first", "second"] since I have ~100 return values?

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [4]: df[['first','second']] = df.body.str.extract(r'(.)(.)', expand=True)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  body first second
0  abc     a      b
1  def     d      e
2  ghi     g      h
```